# useCallback give me infinitive loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have page where I am getting data via getServerSideProps().  But also I have component where user can search data. Search data are sent back to main page and used. Problem is I am getting infinitive loop. Data in console.log() are still fetching..

How can I fetch data only once? Can you please show me what I am doing wrong? tnx

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {

  await connectDB();

  try {

    const animals = await NewEvent.find({})
    
    return {
      props: {
        animals: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animals)),
      }
    }

  } catch (error) {
     return {
      props: {
        notFound: true
      },
    };
  }

}





const Index = ({ animals }) => {
      console.log(animals)   // I am getting data permanently.

   // function to get search data from search component
    const getSearchedData = (data) => {
      console.log(data)     // I am getting data permanently.
      setSearchData(data)
    }


  return (
   <>
     
       {/* Component for searching data */} 
        <SearchAnimals  getSearchedData={getSearchedData} />
```

SearchAnimals  component here with useCalback

```
const Index = ({ getSearchedData }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');



const getData = useCallback(async () => {

  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    // call backend and getting data
    const res = await axios.post(`/api/searchAnimals`, { query: query }, config);

    if (getSearchedData) {
      getSearchedData(res.data.data);
    }


  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
}, [query, getSearchedData]);


  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [query, getData])
```

Comment: all is working properly, but in console.log() and getting still data.  It show me result and on new line again and again.... How to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current setup, getServerSideProps fetches data when the page is loaded on the server side, and then your component has logic to fetch data on the client side as well. This can lead to redundant data fetching.

To resolve this issue, you can modify your component to check if the data has already been fetched before triggering additional requests. You can use a state variable to keep track of whether the initial server-side data fetching has occurred. Here's an example:

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

```
const Index = ({ animals: initialAnimals }) => {
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState(initialAnimals);
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([]);
  const [isServerDataFetched, setServerDataFetched] = useState(true); // Initially set to true

  // Function to get search data from the search component
  const getSearchedData = (data) => {
    setSearchData(data);
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      };

      // Call backend and get data
      const res = await axios.post(`/api/searchAnimals`, { query: query }, config);
      setAnimals(res.data.data);
      setSearchData(res.data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  // Fetch initial data on the client side only if it hasn't been fetched on the server side
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isServerDataFetched) {
      getData();
      setServerDataFetched(true); // Set to true to prevent further client-side fetching
    }
  }, [isServerDataFetched]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* Component for searching data */}
      <SearchAnimals getSearchedData={getSearchedData} />
      {/* Render your data here using the 'animals' state */}
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  await connectDB();

  try {
    const animals = await NewEvent.find({});
    return {
      props: {
        animals: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(animals)),
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        notFound: true,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You have a function that gets some data (let's call it getData). Now, you also have a special function in React called useEffect that runs some code when your component is first loaded or whenever something changes.Now, if you put getData inside useEffect and inside getData you change something that causes a re-render (like updating the state), it can create a loop. This loop happens because changing the state triggers a re-render, and that re-render runs useEffect again, which calls getData, and the cycle repeats.To fix this, you might want to make sure that what's inside getData doesn't cause a constant loop of re-renders.*